# woocommerce_sessions - Table does not exist

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Woocommerce shop - Cart empty after adding products for logged out users only. 
Woocommerce status error : woocommerce_sessions Table does not exist in woocommerce.

I tried deactivating and reactivating plugin. Tried repairing database but got the following error: woocommerce_sessions] Error: Table w'p_woocommerce_sessions' doesn't exist

Tried adding table with SQL query and but I get a 'table exist error'.

```
CREATE TABLE `xxx`.`wp_woocommerce_sessions` ( `session_id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT , `session_key` CHAR(32) NOT NULL , `session_value` LONGTEXT NOT NULL , `session_expiry` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL , PRIMARY KEY (`session_key`(32)), UNIQUE `UNIQUE` (`session_id`(20))) ENGINE = MyISAM;
```

Comment: Sounds like your database is corrupted. The errors you're seeing are related to missing files typically (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6342201/bug-1146-table-xxx-xxxxx-doesnt-exist) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25039927/database-corruption-with-mariadb-table-doesnt-exist-in-engine). Do you have any backups?

Comment: The database backups available is also missing the table. Also tried repairing database via CPanel MySql but I also get the following error "Error: Table 'xx.wp_woocommerce_sessions' doesn't exist"